# user registration doesn't work on remote server, VPS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am deploying my first Laravel project to a VPS. Everything is working fine, I can login as admin, upload images and text to my database BUT I can't register users. The user registration, login, tables etc. are made with 'make:auth', the only thing I have done is added a couple of fields to the user.

The register controller validates all the information but doesn't save it to the database.

It is not giving me any errors in 'storage/logs/laravel.log'. EDIT: not any output at all

The registration is working fine locally.

Thanks.

Comment: On your VPS, in the project folder, check log file `storage/logs/laravel.log`. That should give you more info about the error. Maybe you didn't run some migrations?

Comment: 'storage/logs/laravel.log' is not giving me any output at all.
'DESCRIBE users;' looks like it should be I don't think there is anything wrong with the migration.

Comment: Make sure the storage folder has the correct write permissions, and try adding some logging along the way of your registration.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, in first time I have ever upload my project to my VPS. I think the problem in given null data to registration table. In some server or other phpMyAdmin version not like in your localhost doesn't accept it.

Just make sure from your phpMyAdmin in VPS there is no null data.

Or go to `Table structure` and change columns "Default" to `NULL`.

Just columns that you don't gives data for it.